# Cannot add image to PDF file using PDFsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdfsharp

I am using `ASP.NET` application and I am trying to add a logo to PDF file and when I am not showing the full path, it says that the `logo.png` does not exist.

I have tried to add this picture in many ways, but nothing except full path is working.

This is my code:

```
const string PngSamplePath = "/web_images/logo.png";
XImage image = XImage.FromFile(PngSamplePath);
gfx.DrawImage(image, 220, 120, 50, 50);
```

Comment: Please show how your app directory is conformed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FromFile` waits for a full path of the logo.

So you must use [MapPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms524632(v=vs.90).aspx) to resolve your relative path (`~/web_images/logo.png`) to full path.

**ASP.NET MVC1 -> MVC3**

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/web_images/logo.png");
```

**ASP.NET MVC4**

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~/web_images/logo.png");
```

now `path` become i.e: : `C\MyApplication\web_images\logo.png`

and then:

```
XImage image = XImage.FromFile(path)
```

Comment: it could be more helpful if you can explain what ~ maps to, by providing a link.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing your directory, however you can always just point to the root of your apps directory using the tilde (`~`) and build from there.

```
"~/your/file/path.png"
```